# strange MySQL problem

Tags: mysql

Hey guys I am having problems with MySQL.

Its throws me error when im using this query.

```
update table set column1 = 'test' where column2 = 'xy' and column3 = 'xx'
```

The error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near 'column2 = 'xy' and column3 = 'xx'' at line 1
```

What am i doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: It'd be cool if you said what error it throws. Imagine coming to a car shop and saying "Hi guys, my car is broke, how come?".

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column2 = 'xy' and column3 = 'xx'' at line 1 ^^ these are just example names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give real names and values and real errors.  How do you expect anyone to help you?

Based on your comment on @Will A's answer, it appears that column2 is a reserved word.  Try wrapping it in ticks (`) or write `tablename.columnname` instead of just `columnname`.

Comment: thanks tablename.column worked...guess it was reserved name or something

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Is your table called "table"?  Try:

```
update `table` set column1 = 'test' where column2 = 'xy' and column3 = 'xx'
```

instead.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column2 = 'xy' and column3 = 'xx'' at line 1

^^ these are just example names

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
update tablename set column1 = 'test' where column2 = 'xy' and column3 = 'xx'
```

This is the update syntax for Single-table:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```